# Infinite composition of Logs with infinite argument

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

If you were to compose an infinite number of ln's  what is the result? Is it finite? Does it exist?
Perhaps the most natural way to think about writing down this limit would be as follows:
$$\lim_{a->\infty}\log_a\circ\log_{a-1}\circ...\circ\log_2(a)$$ 
(starting at 1 is obviously not going to work since log(1)=0, leads to the log(log(1)) being divergent.)

The problem with this definition is that the logs kill the 2 too quickly, i.e we get complex evaluations of the function, which is not necessarily bad.

There are various other ways to think about this sort of limit as well. Suppose you already had an infinite composition of logs, then took a limit as x went to infinity. i.e:

$$\lim_{x->\infty}...\log\circ\log\circ...\circ\log(x)$$

who wins, x or the logs. Numerically I have found that composing 6 logs with 10^10,000,000 results in -2.165, which seems to suggest that the logs would win, but things, as we know, tend to act very differently in the limit. Is there another way to think about this limit, or does it not exist, since taking the limit two ways leads to two different results?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider $\log(0.3181315052047641539145421148\pm 1.337235701430689361806834165i)$

Comment: I ran it in my computer, not sure how it relates. Could you extrapolate?

Answer (score 1):

This is about as disastrous a problem as the following since it is a double limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty}x-y=?$$

Whether one 'wins' or not depends on a relationship.  For example, if $x=y$, then

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty}x-y=0$$

If $x=y^2$, then

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty}x-y\to+\infty$$

If $e^x=y$, then

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty}x-y=-\infty$$

etc.

To evaluate the logs with common base, you must set a relationship between $x$ and the amount of logs you are taking, else you are left with a double limit.

For the logarithms that are changing base, see that for any

$$a\in\{2,2^3,2^{3^4},\dots,2^{3^{4^{\dots}}},\dots\}$$

it diverges.  Thus, the limit cannot converge.